# How to better expose your chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've developed a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mopkplcglehjfbedbngcglkmajhflnjk) because I needed something that could make pages view things in greyscale.

I tried addons like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grayscale/oohjdnkmhbhakoafjjgljpifbfjdclna?hl=en) but it was completely broken for me.
Anyway, after creating my own, with a lot more than just 'greyscale' functionality I called it something really generic.

So now I'm worried, anyone searching for 'greyscale' or 'webpage photo filter' wont find my extension!
My question is; is there any way to add tags to your extension listing in the store that searches will take into account? Or do you have suggestions on where I should spout keywords in the current description space?

Comment: I think you can change the name of the extension.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting more exposure for a specific extension in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: but where *would* it be on-topic? it's definitely programming 'related' and a straight question...just not a 'programming question' :P

Comment: I think he means that it seems like you could be trying for free advertising for your extension.  If your question did not reference your specific extension, then you could honestly claim to not be trying for free advertising.

Comment: I can edit it out if that's the issue. I wrote the question in a way you don't have to follow the link, they're just there for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add keywords into your extension's description, either into sentences, bullet points, or just a simple list at the end.

There are no tags in Chrome Web Store listings. You have to get creative with your text.

A suggestion for your description:

> Create your own webpage photo filters!
>
> See things in;
>
> - black and white (greyscale)

Comment: I'll have to look up how to do markup in the description (its not just plain HTML is it?)

Comment: @Hashbrown I'm pretty sure it's just plain text, there's no markup at all.